# Building an inverted peak voltage detector

Tags: voltage, detector

So I am trying to build a detector that will find the lowest voltage dip of a DC source.

So for example, if I attach a load I can see what the voltage drops to.

I have built this peak detector in LTSpice

[image]

But I can't manage to get it to work to stick at the lowest voltage reached.

Do you have any tips?

Answer (score 1):

1. With 0 and 9 V rails, LM741 will only work for input voltages between something like +4 and +5 V. Maybe try this with an ideal op-amp first, then find a better choice than LM741 to get a reasonable common mode input range.
2. The way your diode is oriented, you've made a positive peak detector, not a negative peak detector. Try reversing the diode orientation.

Comment: ... or add a voltage divider, 100 k resistors, to the input circuit so that you do not work close to the supply voltage.

Comment: Yes, I know this is a positive peak detector. Sorry should have been clearer. I would like to modify it to be a negative peak detector. Inverting the diode just gives me an output I've about 1.3v with no change. Completely flat.

Comment: Would you also be able to suggest a better op amp? Should I just try different ones from the library in LTSpice? What features should I be looking for to be closer to ideal?

Comment: @James, depends what input voltage range you need to deal with. If your input might cover the whole 0 to 9 V, then you need something with rail-to-rail on both input and output. And you need something that doesn't go too nuts when saturated...which often isn't mentioned on the datasheet.

Comment: When you say "negative peak detector", do you mean finding the minimum voltage on a positive voltage, or do you mean (as I suspect) finding the minimum voltage on a negative? If the latter, since your op amps are configured with only ground as the - supply, of course they won't produce a usable output. Try running your op amps from +/- 15 volts.

Comment: Ok, how about this? http://i.imgur.com/60lhY5b.png

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast No I mean the former, I want to find the minimum voltage reached by a positive voltage.  Essentially I am trying to test a power supply to see how it copes with a sudden current draw. Test to see if the voltage drops below the minimum for the uC I am using. Then if the spike when the current stops being drawn is over the max rating.

Comment: @James, yes, that's all there is to it.

Comment: @The Photon, weirdly LTSpice seems to get stuck in the simulation if I connect the -v connection of the opamp to ground like I have it for the negative peak detector. Any ideas why?

Comment: @James, I'm not sure. It might just be upset at you for using a TI part. (meaning, TI's models are tested on a different simulator than LTSpice, and might have some syntax that LTSpice doesn't understand).